# MAUI: Reactive Design Specify Max button width but allow buttons to shrink if needed

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have three buttons located below a set of fields that I want to increase in width until a **fixed max size** is reached if the space is available.

[Desired Behaviour Visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmtZ.png)

Maui by default seems to set the buttons to their minimum size to display their text. (As seen in the minimum width part of the image).

My first point of call was to try using the **WidthRequest** property of the button control however this prevents the buttons from being able to shrink.

**MaxWidthRequest/MinWidthRequest** also don’t seem to be the solution either.

MaxWidthRequest still results in the minimum size being used and MinwidthRequest behaves like WidthRequest and prevents the buttons from being able to shrink.

I’ve experimented with both Grid Layout and Horizontal Layout trying to do this. The closest I have come is with a Grid layout with five columns however it doesn’t fully deal with shrinking.

Below is my code with one of my attempts at doing this in the grid and one in a Horizontal Layout.

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5"/>
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <VerticalStackLayout >
        <Label Text="Run Setting" 
                TextColor="White" 
                FontSize="Small"
                Padding="5,3"                   
                BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"/>

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions=" Auto, *, *"
                RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto"
                Padding="10" 
                RowSpacing="10"
                ColumnSpacing="10">

            <Label Text="Min:"  FontSize="Micro" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Max:" FontSize="Micro" Grid.Column="2"/>
            
            <Label Text="Field 1:" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Micro" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Entry Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>

            <Label Text="Field 2:" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Micro" Grid.Row="2"/>
            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            <Label Text="Field 3:" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Micro" Grid.Row="3"/>
            <Entry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *, *, *" Padding="10,5,10,10" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="Save" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  MaximumHeightRequest="170"  />
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="Edit" HorizontalOptions="Fill" MaximumHeightRequest="170" />
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Text="Accounts" HorizontalOptions="Fill" MaximumHeightRequest="170" />
        </Grid>

        <!--<HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="6" Padding="0,5,0,10">
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="Save" WidthRequest="170" />
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="Edit" WidthRequest="170"/>
            <Button BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Text="Accounts" WidthRequest="170"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>-->
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Border>
```

I fully admit I’m new to frontend UI work so I could be coming at this from completely wrong direction. If this is the case, feel free to link to resources on how to do it correctly

**Edit 1 :- After Experimenting with H,A,H Recommendations**

See attached image showing the different behavior between supplied code and Desired behavior.

[H,A,H Vs Desired Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njxLZ.png)

Comment: Check my last edit. Change your indexes from 1/2/3 to 0/2/4.

Comment: VerticalOptions -> HorizontalOptions.

Comment: I wrote you a working example, just copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,Auto,*">
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"            
        Text="MID"
        MaximumWidthRequest="100"
        HeightRequest="50"/>
    <Button
        Grid.Column="0"   
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        Text="LEFT BUTTON"            
        HeightRequest="50"/>
    <Button
        Grid.Column="2"            
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        Text="RIGHT BUTTON"            
        HeightRequest="50"/>
</Grid>
```

Here man, I wrote it for you. I guess I am better at writing than explaining.

Comment: Thanks for your response, If you try the code I included you will see I have tried this and it would work if I wanted the buttons to full all available space at any size. 

However I only want the buttons to fill space up to a max size.

At smallest size ->  |Button|Button|button|
Over max size    -> |Space|Button|Button|button|Space|

Comment: I tried the code. Hundreds of times. Most importantly, few hours ago I had to write one simple page, where I used this once again. I will show you sample of the button.

Comment: H,A,H I think you are getting confused somewhere nowhere do I state button/space/button/space/button. If anything in the post is unclear or confusing let me know and I will edit it to clarify it.

Comment: Here it is. I hope this helps.

Comment: See update and attached image in response to your recommendations.